# Keep every bin while pivoting a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 12 different dataframes, that I can only load sequentially in memory due to system constraints.

The objective is to update bin counts, at each iteration over the different datasets; the preprocessing pipeline for each one is the following:

```
           ID         duration_vs_delay_30    delay_hour_vs_delay_30
0          1                  1.12                    1.12
1          4                  1.13                    1.13
2          5                  1.21                    1.21
3          6                  2.1                     1.7
4         10                  1.95                    1.9
```

Thus, I bin the two numeric columns with two defined lists and use a pivot table to sum all values in each bin:

```
# Define bins
y_axis = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]
x_axis = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]

chunk['bin_y_axis'] = pd.cut(chunk.delay_hour_vs_delay_30, y_axis)    
chunk['bin_x_axis'] = pd.cut(chunk.duration_vs_delay_30, x_axis)  

chunk["count_route"] = 1
```

Then, if we're in the first iteration, I use the following:

```
bin_df = chunk.pivot_table(index='bin_x_axis', columns='bin_y_axis', values='count_route',
                aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value = 0)
```

Else:

```
chunk = chunk.pivot_table(index='bin_x_axis', columns='bin_y_axis', values='count_tratta',
                    aggfunc = np.sum, fill_value = 0)

bin_df = bin_df + chunk
```

However, if the current chunk does not have all the values within the defined bins, I obtain dataframes with less columns and rows than the ones it should have.

How can I correct this error so that columns and rows contain all bins and the main bin_df is sequentially updated?

Answer (score 0):

As you loop through each file, keep a running total for each `(bin_x, bin_y)` tuple and save the pivot for the last:

```
summary = None

# Lop through your files
for file in ...

    # ... process the file ...

    chunk_summary = chunk.groupby(['bin_x_axis', 'bin_y_axis']).size()
    if summary is None:
        summary = chunk_summary
    else:
        summary += chunk_summary

# Save the pivot operation for the last
bin_df = summary.unstack()
```

**Note:** your bins do not cover all values and hence some rows are assigned to bin NaN. `groupby` ignore rows where `bin_x` or `bin_y` is NaN.